# ECLIPSE E4 LUNA - CoreExpression for a HandledToolItem

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm trying to use the same core expression that works like a charm for a HandleMenuItem, also for a HandledToolItem, but unforunaly I got stuck since the compiler doesn't care at all.

The HandledToolItem is never hidden.

So I tried to dig around and it seems there's a known bug for core expression and HandledToolItem, are you aware about that?

Thanks

Comment: It is not at all clear what your question is here! As you seem to have already discovered this is Eclipse bug [400217](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400217)

Comment: @greg-449 it's not clear because I don't know if it's a question either. Well I found this bug on an unreliable source and I was wondering if somebody might confirm it. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: One workaround is managing visibility via java code in handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567917/eclipse-e4-rcp-core-expressions-something-less-xml-hell