# e4 ConcurrentModificationException on ESelectionService setSelection

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4, concurrentmodification

I have a code which sets the active selection of the `ESelectionService` when the user selects something in the tree. Like here:

```
treeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        if (selectionService != null) {
             selectionService.setSelection(((IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection()).getFirstElement());
        }
    }
});
```

where `selectionService` is being injected. So far so good.

I also have some command handlers with their own `canExecute()` methods. In these methods I check the current selection (which is also being injected) and decide if the `canExecute()` method should return true or false. What I also do in this method is, I also change the visibility of the corresponding `HandledToolItem` - like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23602909/2097228.

Now what I experience is that sometimes the call to the `setSelection` method of the `ESelectionService` throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This actually occurs when the [ToolItemUpdater](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/renderers/swt/ToolItemUpdater.java) accesses the `itemsToCheck` `ArrayList`.

Is my approach error-prone or is this just a bug in 4.4?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception occurred
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolItemUpdater.updateContributionItems(ToolItemUpdater.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$8.changed(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:367)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$4.changed(E4Application.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$7.changed(SelectionAggregator.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionServiceImpl.setSelection(SelectionServiceImpl.java:31)
        at com.e4test.parts.SamplePart$TreeViewerSelectionListener.selectionChanged(SamplePart.java:116)
```

Comment: A stack trace of the exception might help

Comment: @greg-449 I edited the post - now with stack trace attached

Comment: Looks like you are managing to change the 'items to check' list in the ToolItemUpdater while it is iterating through that list. Probably in your 'HandledToolItem' 'canExecute' method - show us that code.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought, too. My `canExecute` method only checks the type of the selection (simple instanceof check) and then calls the `setToolItemVisible` method - which is as I pointed out in my question. So it is the setToolItemVisible method that is actually causing the troubles - editing the items which are still referenced by the ToolItemUpdater

Comment: You did keep the Display.asyncExec call in setToolItemVisible? That looks like it is trying to delay the set visible until after the loop completes.

Comment: I think this caused the problem. One of the handlers had Display.syncExec call. At least the exception is not reproducible anymore. Thanks